# How to get the value of a pointer to an int pointer from c++ in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

How to get array of values from the intptr. how to get vlues pointed by int_ptr_arr into s1[].... mean to say my s1[] should contain 10,100,15

it works for me if it is char** with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(), but i want it for int** because i don't have anything like  Marshal.ptrint().... etc..

```
        enter code here
             Native code: 
       extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)    int**  __stdcall Array_hh()
            {
                int x=10;
                int y=100;
                int z=15;
             static int* myArray[3] = {&x, &y, &z};
                return myArray;
            }

            wrapper: 
[DllImport("Native_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
                     public static extern IntPtr Array_hh();
            void some_fun
             IntPtr int_ptr_arr = Wrapper.Array_hh();
                       int k = 0;
                       int[] s1 = new int[4];
```

Comment: You can use Marshal.Copy() on the returned IntPtr.  You'd better use an int[3] however.

Comment: not able to extract the values after doing Marshal.copy.... after doing Marshal.Copy()... addresses are stored, how to get values from these addresses.. can you please paste the working example , if you have...

Comment: Oh, right, you are returning pointers to local variables that are destroyed.  Not valid C code, you cannot make this work.

Comment: even if i make x,y and z... as static , then also not getting